# Value is not updating .. its updating but after refreshing the page but not everytime | Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const availableFunc = (id) => {
  if (Active.length > 0) {
    let available = Active.filter((obj) => obj.type === id).map((obj) =>
      obj.available !== undefined ? obj.available : ""
    );
    return available[0];
  }
};
```

All data is stored in `Active` and the desired value is present in available when I console `available[0]` then I am getting the **correct value** but don't know why it's not updating the value in `defaultValue={}`. Sometime after 5-6 refresh its updated [but I] don't know how!! Again I refresh the page the value goes hidden.

Please **team** and **seniors** help me to solve this problem..

```
<Select
  defaultValue={availableFunc(res.eId)}
  onChange={(event) =>
    handleChangeSelect(
      event.target.value,
      res.eId,
      res.dropDown[0]
    )
  }
>
  {res.vals &&
    res.vals.map((res) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem value={res}>{res}</MenuItem>
      );
  })}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `defaultValue` prop/attribute is *just* the initial value of the input when the component mounts. It's generally used for uncontrolled inputs, i.e. you aren't storing the input's value in state (updated via the `onChange` handler). Changes to this prop don't actually change the value being used by the input, you should be seeing a react warning, something to the effect of "Changing an input from uncontrolled to controlled...".

## Solution

Since you've attached an `onChange` handler I'll assume you meant for this to be a controlled input. Use the `value` prop.

```
<Select
  value={availableFunc(res.eId)}
  onChange={(event) =>
    handleChangeSelect(
      event.target.value,
      res.eId,
      res.dropDown[0]
    )
  }
>
  ...
```